# Modify value from CFormModel in dataProvider array

Tags: php, yii

So another issue... I have to format a number that is set via CFormModel but the thing is, if I var_dump the dataProvider, attributes are not set, yet they appear on the website. Also, if I call $dataProvider->value (where value exists as a public parameter in CFormModel extended class) Yii sais that the value is not set (proves the var_dump() is right)

1. How come?
2. How can I modify the number via number_format() or a Yii-related method?

   ```
   CActiveDataProvider Object
   (
     [modelClass] => VouchersTransactions
     [model] => VouchersTransactions Object
     (
       [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
       [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
           (
           )

       [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
           (
           )

       [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
       [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 
       [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
       [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
           (
           )

       [_validators:CModel:private] => 
       [_scenario:CModel:private] => 
       [_e:CComponent:private] => 
       [_m:CComponent:private] => 
   )

    [keyAttribute] => 
    [_criteria:CActiveDataProvider:private] => CDbCriteria Object
   (
       [select] => *
       [distinct] => 
       [condition] => user_id = 141
       [params] => Array
           (
           )

       [limit] => -1
       [offset] => -1
       [order] => 
       [group] => 
       [join] => 
       [having] => 
       [with] => 
       [alias] => 
       [together] => 
       [index] => 
       [scopes] => 
       [_e:CComponent:private] => 
       [_m:CComponent:private] => 
   )

   [_countCriteria:CActiveDataProvider:private] => 
   [_id:CDataProvider:private] => VouchersTransactions
   [_data:CDataProvider:private] => 
   [_keys:CDataProvider:private] => 
   [_totalItemCount:CDataProvider:private] => 
   [_sort:CDataProvider:private] => 
   [_pagination:CDataProvider:private] => 
   [_e:CComponent:private] => 
   [_m:CComponent:private] => 
   )
   ```

this is the printed dataProvider

```
      $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('VouchersTransactions', array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'user_id = ' . Yii::app()->user->id,
        ),
      ));
```

this is the dataProvider, where VoucherTransactions is a model inside a different Module

**L.E.**

```
    0 => VouchersTransactions#1
    (
      [CActiveRecord:_new] => false
      [CActiveRecord:_attributes] => array
    (
        'id' => '48'
        'user_id' => '141'
        'number_vouchers' => '1'
        'voucher_value' => '0.0100'
        'date_created' => '2014-07-11 10:06:22'
    )
    [CActiveRecord:_related] => array()
    [CActiveRecord:_c] => null
    [CActiveRecord:_pk] => '48'
    [CActiveRecord:_alias] => 't'
    [CModel:_errors] => array()
    [CModel:_validators] => null
    [CModel:_scenario] => 'update'
    [CComponent:_e] => null
    [CComponent:_m] => null
    )
    1 => VouchersTransactions#2
    (
      [CActiveRecord:_new] => false
      [CActiveRecord:_attributes] => array
    (
        'id' => '52'
        'user_id' => '141'
        'number_vouchers' => '1'
        'voucher_value' => '10.0000'
        'date_created' => '2014-07-11 10:15:06'
    )
    [CActiveRecord:_related] => array()
    [CActiveRecord:_c] => null
    [CActiveRecord:_pk] => '52'
    [CActiveRecord:_alias] => 't'
    [CModel:_errors] => array()
    [CModel:_validators] => null
    [CModel:_scenario] => 'update'
    [CComponent:_e] => null
    [CComponent:_m] => null
)
```

This is what I get if I dump $dataProvider->data but I cannot alter informations there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this using the Yii afterSearch() method in the model. Great method to use when you have to modify values like this.

```
  public function afterSave() {
      //do modification here
      return parent::afterSave();
  }
```